# Is it possible to mark one method of an entire @Transactional class as non-transactional

Tags: java, database, hibernate, transactions

I need to maintain the transaction manually in a method of a class which was marked as @Transactional. If I try to do this now, an exception is being thrown (most probably because the transaction is being committed twice, once by me, and twice by the wrapper proxy). What do I need to do.

If this is not possible, then is there a way to get notified when a transaction was successfully committed (data in the DB and everything), so that I call another applciation, which relies on the same DB?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using **spring**. If yes, then you can.

Read this block of code from the API [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html). at section *10.5.6 Using @Transactional*

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class DefaultFooService implements FooService {

 public Foo getFoo(String fooName) {
// do something
}

// these settings have precedence for this method
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void updateFoo(Foo foo) {
 // do something
}
}
```

Comment: Within the method marked with propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, am I allowed to begin/commit transactions manually? I tried it, but I still get the same exception

Comment: Don't add any code to begin,commit or roll back your self, spring will do it for you. In the above example a new transaction will be started at the beginning of the <b>updateFoo()</b> method commited at the last line. If there is any problem in between the transaction will be rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe this is possible.  I believe if you create another thread and execute the code, it will be outside of the transaction though.  Be careful with that, because it can get dicey when you are creating additional threads and managing that yourself.